# Code snippets for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, organization, code-snippets

Is there a good code snippets application for Delphi or general purpose with IDE integration? I would like to store Code, queries, notes, etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dittos to Ozmosys above.

Also check CodeSnip Database Viewer from the delphidabbler:
http://www.delphidabbler.com/software/codesnip

Answer (score 8):

[GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org) has a Code Librarian feature for code snippets amongst many other nice features and integrates with the IDE. Well worth to check out even if you don't decide to use the Code Librarian feature.

Answer (score 3):

Delphi 2006 and later has [Live Templates](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Live_Templates_Technical_Info). They are a bit tricky because you've got to edit XML files to really make them work, but they are powerful when they do.  See [Nick's Live Templates Camtasia Presentation](http://bdntv.borland.com/pix/nickhodges/Camtasia/28LiveTemplates/28LiveTemplates.html). Ctrl-J is the shortcut to invoke this.

Prior to that, Delphi 2005 and earlier had simple code snippets. I believe Ctrl-J also invoked them.

Another option is to use [Castalia](http://www.twodesk.com/castalia/) and its [Code Templates feature](http://www.twodesk.com/castalia/code_templates.html).

Answer (score 1):

I use Knowledgebase from Ozmosys. It hasn't been updated in a while, but it works, and it is written in Delphi. [Ozmosys](http://www.ozmosys.net.au/)

Comment: I use Knowledgebase at my work and it is very slow when loading a topic that has a simple picture in it. Maybe it's fixed in a later release.

Answer (score 0):

I have to endorse Ozmosys' Knowledge Base too. The reason it hasn't been updated in a while is that it just works. When I DID have issues early in the development of the program, the author was very responsive and quick about doing it. It's logical and easy to post code and other types of hints. I use it every day, juggling the three or so projects that seem to be perpetually on my plate.